# C# WPF MVVM switching views

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Hi i've been looking up for the last 2 days but I not get the way to fix my issue.

This is my mainView

MainView.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="STARename.MainView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:PL.STARename.ViewModels"
        xmlns:views="clr-namespace:PL.STARename.Views"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:STARename"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="{Binding Path=Title}" Height="650" Width="825" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:MainViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:LoginViewModel}">
            <views:LoginView />
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:STARViewModel}">
            <views:STARView />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="109*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="166*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="228*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="213*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="101*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="56*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="484*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="79*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Image Source="{Binding ContiLogo}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}" Grid.Column="2" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Engravers MT" FontSize="24" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

LoginView.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="PL.STARename.Views.LoginView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:PL.STARename.ViewModels"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PL.STARename.Views"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Height="567.771" Width="518.51">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="80*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="344*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="87*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="98*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="230*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="209*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <GroupBox x:Name="groupBox" Header="Login" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="Orange">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="18*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="92*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="23*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="70*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="109*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="81*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="35*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="12*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="32*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="44*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="4*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Image Source="{Binding ContiLogo}" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" />
                <TextBlock Text="User:" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" />
                <TextBlock Text="Password:" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" />
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Username, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
                <PasswordBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="3" x:Name="PasswordBox" vm:PassAssist.BindPassword="True" vm:PassAssist.BoundPassword="{Binding Path=Password, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                    <PasswordBox.InputBindings>
                        <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding CmdLogin}" />
                    </PasswordBox.InputBindings>
                </PasswordBox>
                <Button Background="Orange" Content="Login" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Command="{Binding CmdLogin}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=LoginText,Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="4" />
            </Grid>
        </GroupBox>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

STARView.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="PL.STARename.Views.STARView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PL.STARename.Views"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:PL.STARename.ViewModels"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             Height="567.771" Width="518.51">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="STAR" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

BaseViewModel.cs

```
 #region Variables         
        public string Title
        {
            get
            {
                return $"{Settings.Default.AppName} {Settings.Default.AppVersion}";
            }
        }
        public string ContiLogo
        {
            get
            {
                return $@"{Environment.CurrentDirectory}/Others/ContiLogo.png";
            }
        }

        protected virtual void SetProperty<T>(ref T member, T val,
         [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (object.Equals(member, val)) return;

            member = val;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        #endregion
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            VerifyPropertyName(propertyName);
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        [Conditional("DEBUG")]
        private void VerifyPropertyName(string propertyName)
        {
            if (TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this)[propertyName] == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(GetType().Name + " does not contain property: " + propertyName);
        }
        public BaseViewModel()
        {
            //Helpers.BusLayer._BL;
            try
            {
                Helpers.BusLayer._BL.InitorReset();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

MainViewModel.cs

```
public class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        #region Variables
        public LoginViewModel LoginVM;
        public STARViewModel STARVM;
        private BaseViewModel _currentVM;
        public BaseViewModel CurrentViewModel
        {
            get
            {
                return _currentVM;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_currentVM == value)
                    return;
                _currentVM = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CurrentViewModel");
            }
        }
        #endregion
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            LoginVM = new LoginViewModel();
            STARVM = new STARViewModel();
            if (!Helpers.BusLayer.LoginSuccess)
                CurrentViewModel = LoginVM;
            else
                CurrentViewModel = STARVM;
        }

    }
```

Int he LoginViewmodel when my Login is true I want to change my View to STARView/ViewModel but the View did not change.

LoginViewModel.cs

```
  #region Variables
        private ICommand _cmdLogin;
        public ICommand CmdLogin
        {
            get
            {
                return _cmdLogin ?? (_cmdLogin = new CommandHandler(Login, canLogin));
            }
        }

        private string _loginText;
        public string LoginText
        {
            get
            {
                return _loginText;
            }
            set
            {
                _loginText = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("LoginText");
            }
        }
        private string _username;
        public string Username
        {
            get
            {
                return _username;
            }     
            set
            {
                _username = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Username");                                                        
            }   
        }
        private string _password;
        public string Password
        {
            get
            {
                return _password;
            }
            set
            {
                _password = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Password");
            }
        }
        #endregion

        public LoginViewModel()
        {
            //ViewModel = STARVM;
        }
        private void Login(object o)
        {
            LoginText = "";            
            try
            {
                if (Helpers.BusLayer._BL.Login(Username, Password))
                {
                    Helpers.BusLayer.LoginSuccess = true;
                    MainViewModel mainVM = new MainViewModel();                    
                    LoginText = "Ok!";                
                }
                else
                {
                    Password = "";
                    LoginText = "Username or password incorrect";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Password = "";
                LoginText = ex.Message;
            }
        }
        private bool canLogin(object o)
        {
            return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Password) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Username);
        }
```

STARViewModel.cs

```
public STARViewModel()
        {

        }
```

When Login is true.
I want to change my View but it does not do that.

Any help idea ?

Comment: You're only doing the `Helpers.BusLayer.LoginSuccess` check once in your view model's constructor, how does your business logic layer tell the main view model when this value has been updated? It should be creating an event or something (e.g. `OnLoginStatusChanged`) which your `MainViewModel` subscribes to and handles by doing the check again.

Comment: When LoginSucces Im passing the value as true and creating a new MainViewModel(); CurrentViewModel = STARVM;

Comment: Can you show the code that replaces the MainViewModel? (This isn't the normal way of doing things btw, your MainViewModel should never change).

Comment: Actually once you've fixed this I'd go back and start again. In general view models should only ever be created for objects that are part of the GUI visual tree. The way it's designed at the moment you're creating both the LoginViewModel and STARViewModel irrespective of whether the user is currently logging in or has already done so. It's a waste of memory and resources, and sooner later view models will start interfering with each other.

Comment: Ok, I am thinking on do that different. Let me look up for more info and change my code. btw what would be the common way to do it ?

Comment: Actually "start again" was a bit extreme, you're pretty close. Just leave the MainViewModel as is and have it initially create only the LoginViewModel and subscribe to a login event. Then when it detects the event it should change the CurrentViewModel over to a STARViewModel and release any references to the LoginViewModel so that the garbage collector can clean it up. Everything else in your code, including your use of ContentControl and DataTemplate etc, look fine.

Comment: You are the man !.. Thank you.... public MainViewModel()
        {
            LoginVM = new LoginViewModel();
            STARVM = new STARViewModel();
            CurrentViewModel = LoginVM;
            LoginVM.LoginSuccess += LoginVM_LoginSuccess;
        }

        private void LoginVM_LoginSuccess(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CurrentViewModel = STARVM;
        }